# Why does Spark fail with "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V"?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I use Spark Streaming 2.10, Kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0, and Spark-streaming-0-10-2.11-2.10.

```
spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.7.0_80
Branch 
Compiled by user jenkins on 2016-12-16T02:04:48Z
```

I use maven to build the project. The following are the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I use the command to run the application in Eclipse correctly.

```
right click -> run as -> maven build -> clean install -> run
```

However, when I `spark-submit` the application as follows:

```
spark-submit \
  --jars=/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.‌​jar,/opt/ibudata/bin‌​logSparkStreaming/ka‌​fka-clients-0.8.2.2.‌​jar,/opt/ibudata/bin‌​logSparkStreaming/me‌​trics-core-2.2.0.jar‌​,/opt/ibudata/binlog‌​SparkStreaming/spark‌​-streaming-kafka-0-8‌​_2.11-2.1.0.jar,/opt‌​/ibudata/binlogSpark‌​Streaming/zkclient-0‌​.3.jar \
  --class com.br.sparkStreaming.wordcount \
  --master spark:m20p183:7077 \
  --executor-memory 2g \
  --num-executors 3 \
  /opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/jars/wordcounttest8-0.0.1-‌​SNAPSHOT.jar
```

...it fails with the following error:

```
> io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V  at
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:651)
>   at
> io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:240)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.respond(TransportRequestHandler.java:194)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processStreamRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:111)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>   at
> io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>   at
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>   at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>   at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V  at
> org.apache.spark.network.buffer.FileSegmentManagedBuffer.convertToNetty(FileSegmentManagedBuffer.java:133)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:54)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:33)
>   at
> io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
>   ... 36 more
```

any suggestion will be appreciate

After all kinds trying,but no good result, then I tried run-exampe given by Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.8.2.1 or higher)  ,
run example with command: 
bin/run-example streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount 172.18.30.22:9092 \test,

but it reported the same error:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.;

so I doubt it maybe some jars in the classpath caused this problem,  my spark-env.sh :

```
export JAVA_HOME=//opt/jdk1.7
export export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala
export export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop2.7.3
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop  
#export SPARK_MASTER_IP=master1  
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=m20p180:2181,m20p181:2181,m20p182:2181 -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/spark"  
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g  
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1g  
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1g  
export SPARK_WORKDER_CORES=4
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/conf
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar
```

As you can see I added netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar to the classpath ,but it didn't work.
::q!

I also started the example with command:
SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1 ./bin/run-example streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount   172.18.30.22:9092 \test

the output :

```
Spark Command: //opt/jdk1.7/bin/java -cp /opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar:/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/etc/hadoop/ -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --jars /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar,/opt/spark/examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.3.0.jar --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount spark-internal 172.18.30.22:9092 test
========================================
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2017-07-04 18:37:01,123 INFO  [main] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Running Spark version 2.1.0
2017-07-04 18:37:01,129 WARN  [main] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
2017-07-04 18:37:02,304 WARN  [main] spark.SparkConf (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - 
SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to ':/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

2017-07-04 18:37:02,308 WARN  [main] spark.SparkConf (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Setting 'spark.executor.extraClassPath' to ':/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar' as a work-around.
2017-07-04 18:37:02,309 WARN  [main] spark.SparkConf (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Setting 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to ':/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib::/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop2.7.3/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/netty-all-4.1.12.Final.jar' as a work-around.
2017-07-04 18:37:02,524 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Changing view acls to: ibudata
2017-07-04 18:37:02,526 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Changing modify acls to: ibudata
2017-07-04 18:37:02,528 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Changing view acls groups to: 
2017-07-04 18:37:02,530 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Changing modify acls groups to: 
2017-07-04 18:37:02,532 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ibudata); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ibudata); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2017-07-04 18:37:03,091 INFO  [main] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35480.
2017-07-04 18:37:03,127 INFO  [main] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Registering MapOutputTracker
2017-07-04 18:37:03,162 INFO  [main] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Registering BlockManagerMaster
2017-07-04 18:37:03,166 INFO  [main] storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
2017-07-04 18:37:03,167 INFO  [main] storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
2017-07-04 18:37:03,185 INFO  [main] storage.DiskBlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-20f80f78-0e27-462d-b5a4-1e0067308861
2017-07-04 18:37:03,214 INFO  [main] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - MemoryStore started with capacity 408.9 MB
2017-07-04 18:37:03,330 INFO  [main] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
2017-07-04 18:37:03,458 INFO  [main] util.log (Log.java:initialized(186)) - Logging initialized @4162ms
2017-07-04 18:37:03,623 INFO  [main] server.Server (Server.java:doStart(327)) - jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-07-04 18:37:03,652 INFO  [main] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStart(744)) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@ef93f0{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-04 18:37:03,653 INFO  [main] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStart(744)) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@70d9720a{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-04 18:37:03,653 INFO  [main] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStart(744)) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@53ce2867{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-04 18:37:03,654 INFO  [main] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStart(744)) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3bead2d{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-04 18:37:03,654 INFO  [main] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStart(744)) - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5b5b6746{/stages,null,AVAILABLE}
.....................
client.TransportClientFactory (TransportClientFactory.java:createClient(250)) - Successfully created connection to /192.168.22.197:35480 after 64 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2017-07-04 18:37:07,261 INFO  [Executor task launch worker-0] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Fetching spark://192.168.22.197:35480/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar to /tmp/spark-5110e687-a732-4762-8d74-a7c13a035681/userFiles-69ba7cd2-0014-40d7-8ac8-6b73cd07ce41/fetchFileTemp1907532202323588721.tmp
2017-07-04 18:37:07,367 ERROR [shuffle-server-3-2] server.TransportRequestHandler (TransportRequestHandler.java:operationComplete(201)) - Error sending result StreamResponse{streamId=/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar, byteCount=1950712, body=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar, offset=0, length=1950712}} to /192.168.22.197:41069; closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:651)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:240)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.respond(TransportRequestHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processStreamRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:150)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion.<init>(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V
    at org.apache.spark.network.buffer.FileSegmentManagedBuffer.convertToNetty(FileSegmentManagedBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:33)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
    ... 36 more
2017-07-04 18:37:07,379 ERROR [shuffle-client-6-1] client.TransportResponseHandler (TransportResponseHandler.java:channelInactive(126)) - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /192.168.22.197:35480 is closed
2017-07-04 18:37:08,054 INFO  [JobGenerator] scheduler.JobScheduler (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Added jobs for time 1499164628000 ms
```

Comment: How did you start the Spark Standalone? What's the version? Can you paste the master's web UI at http://m20p183:8080?

Comment: this problem have not been solved, not only run my program, but also run the example provided by Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide ,it reports the same error , but I have added newest version netty-all-4.1.1 2.Final  to  spark/jars instead the other version netty jars, but it did not make any difference ,this really confused me a lot!

Comment: How did you run the example? Can you edit your question and add the output of `env`? Can you run the example using `run-example` with `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1 ./bin/run-example` and paste the output to the question? Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure that you don't set `SPARK_CLASSPATH`? Please re-run `run-example` with `SPARK_CLASSPATH=` before the command, i.e. `SPARK_CLASSPATH= run-example`. I think `SPARK_CLASSPATH` is the culprit.

Comment: I tried the command with spark_classpath:SPARK_CLASSPATH= ./bin/run-example streaming.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount   172.18.30.22:9092 \test.It reported anther error:java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: It seems the error became  more serious

Comment: can you paste your spark_classpath or your spark_env.sh? thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you running a vanilla Spark downloaded from spark.apache.org or some Hadoop distribution like CDH or HDP? What did you change `spark-env.sh`?

Comment: run on hadoop 2.7.3   ， It is a apache hadoop .the spark_env.sh changed is shown in the question ,

Answer (score 4):

After all kinds trying ,finally it was resolved by add the netty-4.0.42.Final to the spark_classpath,  must remember that your spark is a cluster ,not only change the master ,but also change the slaves , is that the reason that blocked me a long time . 
At last ,Many thanks for  Jacek Laskowski ,you're very kindful.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm still puzzled why you did so many changes to your environment that in the end required the extra `netty-4.0.42.Final` jar?!

Comment: I’m also puzzled, It is the  Operation Engineer did that .

Comment: Talk to the engineer since Spark may have been broken by how it was installed. Unless there are valid reasons, I'd avoid operating such Spark installation.

Comment: thanks, man for 3 days i was fixing this issue on the thread. this post helped!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to `spark-submit` with the following jars:

```
--jars=/opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.‌​jar,/opt/ibudata/bin‌​logSparkStreaming/ka‌​fka-clients-0.8.2.2.‌​jar,/opt/ibudata/bin‌​logSparkStreaming/me‌​trics-core-2.2.0.jar‌​,/opt/ibudata/binlog‌​SparkStreaming/spark‌​-streaming-kafka-0-8‌​_2.11-2.1.0.jar,/opt‌​/ibudata/binlogSpark‌​Streaming/zkclient-0‌​.3.jar
```

You only want to include `spark‌​-streaming-kafka-0-8‌​_2.11-2.1.0.jar` that could also be too high as compared to your deployment environment.

```
--jars=/opt/ibudata/binlog‌​SparkStreaming/spark‌​-streaming-kafka-0-8‌​_2.11-2.1.0.jar
```

You should remove `--jars` from `spark-submit`.

I'd start with a local deployment environment first and only when it runs `spark-submit` the Spark application to Hadoop YARN.

Try the following first and get it working:

```
spark-submit \
  --jars /opt/ibudata/binlog‌​SparkStreaming/spark‌​-streaming-kafka-0-8‌​_2.11-2.1.0.jar \
  --class com.br.sparkStreaming.wordcount \
  /opt/ibudata/binlogSparkStreaming/jars/wordcounttest8-0.0.1-‌​SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note that `--jars` does not use `=` to specify the parameters (I didn't know it'd be accepted).

My *guess* is that you `spark-submit` to the environment with a different Spark version which is below `2.1.0` and is incompatible with what you bundled in an uber jar (I *suspect* that you assembled an uber jar that you eventually `spark-submit`).

As you can see in the stack trace the error is due to:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion(Ljava/io/File;JJ)V
  at org.apache.spark.network.buffer.FileSegmentManagedBuffer.convertToNetty(FileSegmentManagedBuffer.java:133)
```

[That particular line 133](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/common/network-common/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/network/buffer/FileSegmentManagedBuffer.java#L133) was changed quite recently in [[SPARK-15178][CORE] Remove LazyFileRegion instead use netty's DefaultFileRegion](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/6e268b9ee32eb93d1a757c6073dd69e86b9df617) and is only available in 2.1.0 and higher which you happen to use.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency, do not skip version tag keep it

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.42.Final</version>
</dependency>
```